# In gradle multi-project, how to build single jar and publish it to maven?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle

First of all, please forgive my poor English. :P

The project structure is as follows:

```java
parent
|-- admin // spring boot web application for management.
|   |-- client // SDK for other applications. publish it to maven.
|   |   |-- src
|   |   `-- build.gradle
|   |-- public // common part of admin and client of it. Such as DTOs.
|   |   |-- src
|   |   `-- build.gradle
|   |-- src
|   `-- build.gradle
|-- common // common part of admin and server.
|   |-- src
|   `-- build.gradle
|-- public // common part of admin, server and clients of them.
|   |-- src
|   `-- build.gradle
|-- server // spring boot web application for normal user.
|   |-- client // SDK for other applications. publish it to maven.
|   |   |-- src
|   |   `-- build.gradle
|   |-- public // common part of server and client of it. Such as DTOs.
|   |   |-- src
|   |   `-- build.gradle
|   |-- src
|   `-- build.gradle
|-- build.gradle
`-- settings.gradle
```

When I publish `:server:client` to maven, it puts `:server:public` in the pom file as a dependency. This requires me to also publish `:server:public` and `:public` to maven separately.

But what I want is to have `:server:client` as a single library and include the class files from `:server:public` and `:public` in it.

In addition, there are similar problems when building `:server` as a spring boot application. It builds the dependent projects into jars and then packages them into `:server`. Rather than packaging their class files.

Is it possible to make gradle work as I expected? Or is there any better design that can meet the reuse of code without publishing multiple libraries?

There is a demo project: https://github.com/cody1996/demo-gradle-build

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do as you want to, with gradle. Either, you can use a gradle plugin to do the job creating a single jar or you can use a custom task to manually pick up the class files from different sub-projects and create a single artifact out of the same.

standard gradle fat jar plugin -
[shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)

If you want to manually do -

```
task singleJar(type: Jar) {
   baseName = 'app-jar'
   from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
   with jar
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this configuration, but it doesn't work. Is this compatible with the `maven-publish` plugin?

Comment: This only appears to answer half the question, and the auxiliary half at that. The main focus of the OP's question is _how to publish_ the fat JAR to a Maven repository.

Comment: @Cody I believe you have to add the fat JAR artifact to the [publications](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:publications). On a different but related note, you may also have to consider possible legal issues from packaging third-party code with your own.

Comment: @Slaw I do not want to package third-party code in my library. I just want package my own code in this multi-project, and import the third-party dependencies by maven pom as normal. Will the above configuration package all code including third-party code in my jar?

Comment: I will say, these are two independent things. We clarified about the fat jar creation, either with plugin or custom task. Now maven or newer maven-publish plugin can do the job of publishing. You need to add the shadowJar to the artifacts. If you don't want to publish other artifacts you can clear the default list as well. See this thread for detail https://discuss.gradle.org › using-pu...
Using publish-plugin to publish a plugin not created by jar task - Plugin Portal - Gradle ...

Comment: @Cody Yes, I believe both the Shadow plugin, and the manual-task example given above, will include all the third-party dependencies in your fat JAR. There should be a way to only include the code of your projects, at least when using a custom task, but I don't currently have a solution (maybe a custom configuration is one option?).

Comment: @Shankhanil Das yes, but the link you provided to the thread looks broken.

Comment: @Slaw I also thought about it this way. But I don't know how to achieve it. I have limited knowledge of gradle, so all my attempts have failed. :(

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-publish-plugin-to-publish-a-plugin-not-created-by-jar-task/29069

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve this. I basically need to keep source code organized in modules but this does not mean that I want to spread a number of maven dependencies on a repository. Android plugin works like this, Spring Boot also, but there is no working example in the whole internet for simple java projects.

Answer (score 1):

After constantly trying, I wrote this configuration.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        internalDependencies = [
                project(':public'),
                project(':server-public')
        ]
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'signing'

dependencies {
    internalDependencies.each {
        internal it
    }

    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web'
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.internal.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
    from {
        internalDependencies.collect {
            it.sourceSets.main.allJava
        }
    }
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
}

javadoc {
    if (JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible()) {
        options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
    }
    source internalDependencies.collect { it.sourceSets.main.allJava }
    classpath += files(internalDependencies.collect { it.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath })
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    from javadoc
    archiveClassifier = 'javadoc'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar
            pom {
                name = 'Server Client Library'
            }
            pom.withXml {
                Node pomNode = asNode()
                pomNode.dependencies.'*'.each {
                    Node temp = it
                    internalDependencies.each {
                        if (temp.groupId.text() == it.getGroup() && temp.artifactId.text() == it.getName()) {
                            temp.parent().remove(temp)
                            return false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
}
```

This has basically met my needs. But it's not elegant enough.

Is there a way to get projects through my custom configuration?

This will eliminates the need to list dependencies or even transitive dependencies through a list.

Comment: Hi Cody, I've tried using your script but InteliJ screams that ```Could not find method internal()``` what is that method?

Comment: @ErvinCosic For a complete example, please refer to the github repository I left in the question. The method-1 branch is a slightly improved version. The final code may be different from the one in this comment, but it should work.